# How do I know what element was dragged in via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I am using jquery draggable and I am handling the stop event.  I need to know the ID of the LI element that was dragged in.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `target` property of the `event` should be the draggable:

```
stop: function(event, ui) { 
    console.log(event.target.id); // Assuming it has an ID
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/asevam) | [source](http://jsbin.com/asevam/edit)

Answer (score 3):

`ui` object has `.helper` property, which represents dragged `jQuery` object. You can retrieve  element's `id` from it in this way:

```
stop: function(event, ui) { 
    alert( ui.helper[0].id );         // here it is
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HpUG7/)